# Initialize different templates with same name in C++

Tags: c++, class, initialization

I have a program written in C++ where the user is able to segment some cells from a microscopy image. When this is done, the program got three overall parameters to change. Those three being `feature`, `classifier` and `reductionMethod`.

Each of these parameters are made as templates which are equal in their initialization. I thought that I could make the following implementation to call this:

```
if (feature == 1)
{
    FastColorIntensityGradientFeature<8> workingFeature();
}
else if (feature == 2)
{
    ColorIntensityGradientFeature<8> workingFeature();
}
workingFeature(input, var, var);
```

But this is not possible, because the `workingFeature` is initialized in the `if-else` statement. How can I do this instead? I'm not that used to programming in C++.

Comment: its not correct on multiple fronts, including neither of those actually declaring objects; they declare functions. And it would appear to me you need a base-virtual class that roots both templates if you want to pursue this.

Comment: I'm surprised this compiles... Any way you can you post more code?

Comment: I find your question a bit unclear and I may have misunderstood it, but I think what you need is [Boost Variant class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Comment: `the workingFeature is initialized in the if-else statement` No it's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the templates can have a common base class, then you can create a pointer of type base, and then create the desired child in the `if` clause.

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual void workingFeature(input, var, var);  
};

template<int num>
class FastColorIntensityGradientFeature : public base
{
public:
    virtual void workingFeature(input, var, var);  
};


template<int num>
class ColorIntensityGradientFeature: public base
{
public:
    virtual void workingFeature(input, var, var);  
};
```

and then change your `if` clause to:

```
base * choice;
if (feature == 1)
{
    choice = new FastColorIntensityGradientFeature<8>;
}
else if (feature == 2)
{
    choice = new ColorIntensityGradientFeature<8>;
}
else
{
        // some error handling
}

choice->workingFeature(input, var, var);
```

You didn't specify the argument types for your function, but obviously they will need to be there in the class definitions.

Answer (score 3):

One way to make it work is to move your code into a function that has a template parameter taking the feature type you want to deal. Sample:

```
template <typename IntensityGradientFeature>
void doWork() {
  IntensityGradientFeature workingFeature;
  workingFeature.doSomething();
}
```

Then you call this way:

```
if (feature == 1)
    doWork< FastColorIntensityGradientFeature<8> >();
else if (feature == 2)
    doWork< ColorIntensityGradientFeature<8> >();
```

Comment: Or take the object in as a parameter to the template function, relying on type deduction. Then you can pass arguments to the constructor at the call site, if you want.